# How to update the records of a table having a subquery which returns all the table's records that I want to modify?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

'Cuentas' is the table that I want to modify; 'Cuentas.saldo' is the attribute inside 'Cuentas' that I want to set.

The inner query works fine by itself, but not with an update statement.

```
UPDATE cuentas
SET    cuentas.saldo = (SELECT ( Nvl(R.valor, 0) + Nvl(D.valor, 0) ) - (
                                                      Nvl(I.valor, 0) +
                                                      Nvl(Cr.valor, 0) )
                        FROM   cuentas C
                               LEFT OUTER JOIN movimientos
       ON( C.numero_cuenta = movimientos.numero_cuenta )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN oficinas
       ON( oficinas.codigo_oficina = C.codigo_oficina )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN movimientos R
       ON( R.numero_cuenta = C.numero_cuenta
           AND R.tipo = 'R' )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN movimientos D
       ON( D.numero_cuenta = C.numero_cuenta
           AND D.tipo = 'D' )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN movimientos I
       ON( I.numero_cuenta = C.numero_cuenta
           AND I.tipo = 'I' )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN movimientos Cr
       ON( C.numero_cuenta = Cr.numero_cuenta
           AND Cr.tipo = 'C' )
       WHERE  C.numero_cuenta = cuentas.numero_cuenta)
```

Comment: Try `UPDATE Cuentas
SET Cuentas.saldo=(NVL(R.valor,0) + NVL(D.valor,0)) - (NVL(I.valor,0) + NVL(Cr.valor,0))
FROM Cuentas  LEFT OUTER JOIN ...` and don't use alias c for Cuentas

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL developer and Oracle APEX.